# How to perform 301 redirection for home page and sub pages using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

We have a global website and local websites for some countries. Now we need to redirect all local sites to global website in a way that we have each countries main page on global website. We are going to use sub pages of global site. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/uk
Redirect 301 /about-us/ http://newdomain.com/about-us/
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://newdomain.com/contact-us/
```

Its working for home page but not working for sub pages. Instead of redirecting them to "http://newdomain.com/about-us/" it keep redirecting to "http://newdomain.com/ukabout-us/"

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NEVER USE 301 REDIRECTS

(unless 1) you know what you are doing 2) you know the consequences of what you are doing 3) you have extensively tested the configuration using 302 redirects).

I'm guessing that none of the 3 provisions above have been met in your case.

There is an [implicit wildcard](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) on the first path supplied as an argument to Redirect. To force a literal match, use RedirectMatch with anchors (e.g. "^/$"). Make sure you use 302 until you've got it working properly.

BTW getting the 301 redirects out of your browser is difficult - just clearing the cache does not always work.